# How can I run jQuery if($(this) statements to send browser.runtime.sendMessage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

How can I use jQuery if($(this) to update my extensions badge? I've tried the code below and it doesn't work.

```
jQuery("a[onclick*='ga']").removeAttr('onclick');
if($(this).attr('onclick') == 'ga'){
    var add = browser.runtime.sendMessage(message, 'Removed += 1')
}
```

It should add +1 for each element matching `a[onclick='ga']` because that's what it's going to block.

The required scripts for the extension:

*manifest.json*

```html
{
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "Anti Click Tracking",
     "version": "2.2.4",
     "description": "Remove Known HTML <a> and <link> Click Tracking Attributes.",
  "background": {
     "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
  "content_scripts": [
            {
         "js": [
             "/jquery/jquery-3.4.0.min.js", "remove.js"
                ],
         "matches": [
             "<all_urls>"
           ]
       }
   ],
"permissions": ["<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"],
}
```

*background.js*

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    
    if (!message) return
    if (message <= 0) return
    const text = message.toString()
    
    chrome.tabs.get(sender.tab.id, function(tab) {

        // Pre-rendered tab has been nuked
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) return

        // Tab is visible
        if (tab.index >= 0) {
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
                tabId: tab.id,
                text: text
            })

            return
        }

        // Invisible pre-rendered tab
        const tabId = sender.tab.id
        chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function update(details) {
            if (details.tabId == tabId) {
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
                    tabId: tabId,
                    text: text
                })
                
                chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.removeListener(update)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

*remove.js*

```js
// Remove ping attribute from <a> (somewhat based on PingBlock)
window.onload = function() {
    
 let Removed = 0
    const anchorElements = document.getElementsByTagName('A')
    
    for (element of anchorElements) {
        if (!element.getAttribute('ping')) continue
   console.log("Removed ping: " + element.getAttribute('ping'))
    element.removeAttribute('ping')
    Removed += 1
    chrome.extension.sendMessage(Removed)
    }
}

// Remove Link Tracking
link();

function link(){
 
 jQuery("a[onclick*='ga']").removeAttr('onclick');
 jQuery("a[onclick*='_gaq.push']").removeAttr('onclick');
 jQuery("link[rel*='pingback']").removeAttr('rel');

}
```

All this code together only updates the badge when the ping attribute is blocked. I need it to also update the badge when jQuery removes the selected attributes. Is it possible to use the `Removed += 1` like I did under the first part for jQuery or will I have to change it to something else?

Comment: It's unclear where this code runs, and what the error is, so we have to guess instead of giving a certain answer. If this is inside a page code, you need to modify your extension, see [Sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @wOxxOm I've updated it, anything else I need?

Comment: So where is this new code? If it's inside remove.js, which is a content script, simply use `chrome` instead of `browser` because it's a chrome extension. P.S. To keep using `browser` you need to load [WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill).

Comment: @wOxxOm so.. changing `browser` to `chrome` should fix it?

Edit: Tried that and it didn't work

Comment: It's not dangerous so just go ahead and try it. Also pay attention to spelling: it should be `chrome`.

Comment: Also, "it didn't work" is too vague. You need to debug the code in devtools or at least show us the error message.

Comment: Also, when you change the content script you need to reload both the extension on chrome://extensions page and the web page.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll play with it when I get home. And there was no error it just didn't update the badge for the icon. Thanks for the help though!